# Convert Instant to OffsetDateTime then Instant.parse() on the OffsetDateTime leads to DateTimeParseException for zero seconds cases

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I am receiving instant from a service and below are the cases.

In first case, say `instant = "2021-03-23T04:17:35Z"` & In second case,
`instant = "2021-07-15T05:27:00Z"`

Then required to convert instant to offsetDateTime, doing like

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Now I want to calculate hours gap between above offsetDateTime and instant.now

```
ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(Instant.parse(offsetDateTime), Instant.now())
```

Results

> case 1 :  it works fine
>
> case 2 :  ERROR : `DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-07-15T05:27Z' could not be parsed at index 16`

**Figured out the reason :**
in case 2, if it would have pass the same `2021-07-15T05:27:00Z`. it would work but as `instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` internally will call to below method, ***where zero would be removed***, basically minute part will be sorted out. so below fn will return `2021-07-15T05:27Z` , this will lead to DateTimeParseException.

```
public static OffsetDateTime ofInstant(Instant instant, ZoneId zone) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(instant, "instant");
        Objects.requireNonNull(zone, "zone");
        ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();
        ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset(instant);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(instant.getEpochSecond(), instant.getNano(), offset);
        return new OffsetDateTime(ldt, offset);
    }
```

One solution I am assuming manually append the zero but that's might not be good practice.

Comment: I downvoted because your question is unclear and you are not showing us the code that fails. A [mre] would greatly help.

Comment: Ole V.V. I tried explain with whatever I had, I noted the root cause in question, So error was parsing failed in Insant, cleared by @Arvind that i just need to take offsetDate time and directly can do conversion, no such parse/formatter require to convert the job. And I was able to calculate the ChronoUnit.HOURS.betweenfor henceforth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You do not need any `DateTimeFormatter`

You do not need any `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your Date-Time strings. The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant1 = Instant.parse("2021-03-23T04:17:35Z");
        Instant instant2 = Instant.parse("2021-07-15T05:27:00Z");

        System.out.println(instant1);
        System.out.println(instant2);

        System.out.println(ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(instant1, instant2));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-23T04:17:35Z
2021-07-15T05:27:00Z
2737
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/GMak06)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: But in this case, DateTimeFormatter would be required

System.out.println("== before =="+offsetDateTime); 
System.out.println("== after ==  "+ offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));

later on i can even parse with the above instant.parse(offsetDate)

Comment: @toxi_code - If you want to ***format*** a `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` obtained from an `Instant`, you will need a `DateTimeFormatter`. You will need a `DateTimeFormatter` also when you want to ***parse*** a Date-Time string that does not conform to ISO8601 format. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: yes, correct `ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(Instant.parse(offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)), Instant.now())` solved the concern.

Comment: @toxi_code - No, do not do it like that. If for some reason, you need to convert `offsetDateTime` to an `Instant`, simply do it as `offsetDateTime.toInstant()` i.e.  you should do it as `ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(offsetDateTime.toInstant(), Instant.now())`. For this, there is no need to use `DateTimeFormatter` which is not only unnecessary but also error-prone.

Comment: Right!!,  DateTimeFormatter not required then.

Answer (score 6):

The [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68471321/642706) is correct.

In addition, let’s look at this code from the Question:

```java
public static OffsetDateTime ofInstant(Instant instant, ZoneId zone) 
{
        Objects.requireNonNull(instant, "instant");
        Objects.requireNonNull(zone, "zone");
   
        ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();
        ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset(instant);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(instant.getEpochSecond(), instant.getNano(), offset);

        return new OffsetDateTime(ldt, offset);
}
```

Firstly, if you want to apply an offset to a moment, there is no need for `LocalDateTime` class. Simply do this:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( myZoneOffset ) ;
```

See the [tutorial on naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html) for `at…`, `from…`, `with…`, etc.

When you want to perceive a moment thought the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to an `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Use `ZonedDateTime` rather than `OffsetDateTime`. A `ZonedDateTime` is preferable to a mere `OffsetDateTime` because it contains more information. This information may be critical if adding or subtracting to move to another moment. This information is also useful when producing text to represent the content of this date-time object.

Understand that an offset from UTC is simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by politicians.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( myZoneId ) ;
```

So your method should be something like this.

```
public static ZonedDateTime ofInstant(Instant instant, ZoneId zone) 
{
    ZonedDateTime zdt = 
        Objects.requireNonNull( instant )
        .atZone(
            Objects.requireNonNull( zone )
        )
    ;
    return zdt ;
}
```

If you really need a `OffsetDateTime`, despite `ZonedDateTime` being preferred, extract one.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Comment: True Basil, That's also the useful knowledge shared as a top up. Thanks n keep sharing the good facts.

Comment: @Basil I believe you are quoting and criticizing source code from the java.time library that the OP pasted into the question as a partial explanation of what went wrong. I agree that a method in an application should not be written like that, but I think that the code in the library is fine here. I also agree that the question isn’t clear and should have included more of the OP’s own code instead.